# How to change the product view page design Magento 2?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am new to magento 2. I am stuck in product view page design. I need to change the design of my product detail page. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can change product page design from the xml.

copy `catalog_product_view.xml from vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout` to your theme.

1- if you want to change the layout like 1 column or 2 column then you w'll need to change by following way.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

2- You can move block using move.

```
<move element="name.of.an.element" destination="name.of.destination.element" as="new_alias" after="name.of.element.after" before="name.of.element.before"/>
```

3- call any static block in magento2 by below code.

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: what is the best way to find out the name of an element?